# Color of text in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After update Android studio, the color of text in the following situation changes automatically...
I just cannot find the option in the Setting>Editor>Colors&Fronts.

[image]

Does anyone know where to set the text color back to white?

Any response will be helpful!

Comment: You need to change theme to default one.

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear. I wanna keep my theme, and just change the text color which represents [ Cannot resolve symbol '...' ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio have two themes built in, Default and Dracula.
Setting>Editor>Colors & Fonts > Choose Default, and if you want more style you can get at [Color Themes](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes).

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear. I wanna keep my theme, and just change the text color which represents [ Cannot resolve symbol '...' ].

Comment: yes, you can change text colors , click in color value, if color value is disabled, Uncheck  'Use inherited attributes', see in http://imgur.com/X0uXwBh

Comment: Don't forget to backup current theme :D